# HKSampleQuery producing unexpected results

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to get all records from HealthKit for `.bodyMass` with `private let healthType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)!` and this query code:

```
let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(
            withStart: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1546300800000),
            end: Date(),
            options: .strictEndDate
)

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)

let query = HKSampleQuery(
           sampleType: healthType,
           predicate: mostRecentPredicate,
           limit: 20, 
           sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]
) { (query, results, error) in
    guard let quantityResults = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
       completion(nil) 
    }

    // quantityResults will be an empty array, with 0 values.

    // some more irrelevant code for now
}

healthStore.execute(query)
```

However, I'm receiving a `results` array in the callback of `18235 values` where in Health app, I only have like 20. Also, when I try to cast the results to `HKQuantitySample`, there's no values anymore. Am I using the framework wrong, or is something else at play?

More context: I'm running this code in a WatchKit extension with a WatchKit app.

Comment: Just a question: did you "just" look at the diagrams or explicitly show your data with "show all data"?

Comment: @Chris How do you mean?

Comment: I mean in the health app